# Can I make my armorstand hold a flowerpot block on its head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried making it hold a flower pot on its head but the result was nothing. When I tried the same thing on its hand it would just show the item.

This is my syntax:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"flower_pot",Count:1}]}
```

I have been searching on the wiki for those datatag things but I'm not really pro at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Not in 1.8

While your command works in principle, as of 1.8.8 the game is unable to render many items in the head slot, including flower pots.

#### Kind of in 1.9

However, as part of the new Snapshots/Upcoming version 1.9, Mojang Dev Grum (Erik Broes) has worked on [rendering all item on entities](https://twitter.com/_grum/status/623411853109141504) and [published a world](https://twitter.com/_grum/status/627923649828360193)  showing off zombies wearing items, including flower pots:

[image: Grum's Army]

Sadly, this will still only display the item as if lying on the ground, rather than the rendered version of a flower pot (the tile entity), and it will be placed at the back of the head (like the flowers in the screenshot above), meaning it will float above the armor stand.

Also note that the `Equipment` tag was split into `ArmorItems` (Feet, Legs, Chest, Head) and `HandItems` (Mainhand, Offhand) to accomodate dual-wielding, so the command would be

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"flower_pot",Count:1}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer. Instead of using the flowerpot block I used the item wich didn't look that bad for my purpose. Also thanks for the information regarding the syntax for 1.9, it will probably come in handy later.